# Why can't I connect to my Raspberry Pi through SSH on my PC or a phone app?

Tags: raspbian, python

I tried to SSH into my Pi using PuTTY, but I got an error:

```
Network Error: Connection timed out
```

I have checked my router, noted that the device is indeed connected to the network, I was able to use the internet to search Google on the Raspbian OS (that required a dedicated monitor and keyboard and mouse which is troublesome). but what I want is to be able to SSH into the OS wirelessly.

I have managed to use port forwarding, and connected via SSH into the Pi through the router IP address, but once inside, I could not do anything that required wireless input, such as updating the RPi or cloning from GitHub etc, it just shows as errors.

```
sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.101  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:feb2:2c6c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:b2:2c:6c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 60  bytes 8148 (7.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 83  bytes 13665 (13.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: I assume that you have enabled ssh via sudo raspi-config or by putting a empty file called ssh on the sd card, right?

Comment: yes, i actually put an empty file, and repeated enabling ssh on the sudo raspi-config as well

Comment: try using ping and your ip to see if you can reach the pi with your computer

Comment: it shows destination host unreachable weird

Comment: Are you using the ip or localhost to try it? Also, I don't think that it's going to be an issue.. but let's try.. are the pi and the pc both wireless or wired?

Comment: i manage to get in through the router's ip, using putty, ifconfig works, both pi and pc are both wireless and on the same router, cant seem to enter through the rpi's ip address, it keeps giving the first error shown above

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to go now...

Comment: 1. Have you tried using `ssh` to access the RPi locally from the same subnet, *without* going through your router? 2. How is the RPi configured for networking? Is it assigned an IP address via DHCP, or statically configured? 3. What is the command line you are using with `ssh`? Are you referencing the RPi via IP or hostname? Based on your update 1, you should be able to access it locally using its IP address. Once on, check to verify that the default gateway is set properly via `sudo route -n`. If that is correct, verify your dns settings.

Comment: And just to double check, you have the same netmask on the router as on the Raspberry Pi, `255.255.252.0`? And what is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` since you cant resolv names?

Comment: Have you configured iptables or ufw on your Raspberry? sudo ufw status To get a more complete output: sudo ufw status verbose Let us know the results.

Comment: Why is the `python` tag here, it is a network related problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Network Error: Connection timed out

There are only two ways that can happen:

1. The system you are trying to reach is running a firewall configured to silently drop packets.  That is not a good practice -- it is better for all concerned that the firewall explicitly reject a connection -- and you would have had to intentionally configure it that way yourself.
2. There is no system on the network using the IP address you are trying to reach.

Note that "SSH is not running" is *not* on that list.  If this were the problem, you would immediately get "Connection refused", because the operating system does in fact reply if no application is using the relevant port.

I have observed that it is possible for a system to be assigned an IP address that works to initiate and maintain connections, but the router still fails to route other parties who wish to initiate a connection with it (i.e., the Pi can access the LAN and internet, but nothing can access it unless the connection was initiated from the Pi).

Comment: theres definitely the ip address on the network as i am able to see it on the router map in the router settings section. it might be firewall configured, but im not sure if theres a firewall configured to drop packets, is that a router option or a firewall on my pc option? i disabled firewall on my pc already

Comment: Neither your router nor the Pi would be doing that unless you intentionally configured it that way; as I said it is considered a bad practice.  Just that's the only possibility beyond "destination (literally) unreachable".  Nodes that can connect always reply to each other, even if it is to say, "I won't connect any further".   But a timeout means there was no response at all.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem `Network Error: Connection timed out` is most likely the router. Some routers deny communication between clients (and there is an option to turn that off, usually). It's a Windows thing - virus protection... That explains you being able to connect using port forwarding.

The second error you get `ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution` means that there is a problem with the DNS setup on the RPi. Check what you have in `/etc/resolv.conf` with `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Try adding as first line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and see if it works (this is Google's public DNS server). No idea what the problem could be, because you said logging in with keyboard and monitor makes DNS work (check /etc/resolv.conf in that situation also).

Answer (score 0):

Update to the situation, I have decided to just use the alternative which is the use the OTG setup to SSH into the Pi instead of dealing with the internet related issues.